# Android method onSuccess() of AsyncHttpClient is deprecated. Is there an alternative for this?

Tags: android, deprecated, asynchttpclient

```
@Override    
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    progressDialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: What library provides `AsyncHttpClient`? It is not a part of the Android API.

Comment: I'm kind of really new to Android programming @ianhanniballake. I have 'AsyncHttpResponseHandler' as the library i think. I will try to import JsonHttpResponseHandler to see if this solves it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake it uses the support library com.loopj.android:android-async-http.
You can check this link about its implementation https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html

Answer (score 0):

Just Update library to 1.4.9

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
//code here 
}
```